# How to multiply each column in a dataframe with a row from another dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes shown below; I want to multiply each column of df1 with each value in the corresponding row in df2. Each time should produce a new column. (It is better explained with an example).

Df1 (in my actual problem there are +1000 rows)

```
    'Fert 1'  'Fert 2'   'Fert 3'
A     1000      900        800
B     100       90         80
C     10        9          8
D     0.1       0.9        0.8
```

Df2 (smaller df where the row names are the same as df1 column names)

```
            'L1'  'L2' 
'Fert 1'     1     0.5   
'Fert 2'     2     0
'Fert 3'     1     0.5
```

Desired result: Basically I want df1 that has been multiplied by df2 and expanded (I want the column names to be multi-index). I can do it with a nested loop although I can't get the correct column headers that way. And looping seems like an inefficient way of doing it because it gets slow with my bigger dataset. I am hoping it can be done using a merge or concat but I just can't work it out.

```
        'Fert 1'      'Fert 2'        'Fert 3'
      'L1'    'L2'  'L1'    'L2'    'L1'    'L2'
A     1000    500    1800     0      800     400
B     100     50     180      0      80      40
C     10      5      18       0      8       4
D     0.1     0.05   1.8      0      0.8     0.4
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), repeat columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) so possible multiple by `Series` with [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
s = Df2.stack()
df = Df1.reindex(s.index, axis=1, level=0).mul(s)
print (df)
  'Fert 1'         'Fert 2'      'Fert 3'       
      'L1'    'L2'     'L1' 'L2'     'L1'   'L2'
A   1000.0  500.00   1800.0  0.0    800.0  400.0
B    100.0   50.00    180.0  0.0     80.0   40.0
C     10.0    5.00     18.0  0.0      8.0    4.0
D      0.1    0.05      1.8  0.0      0.8    0.4
```